# System.Configuration with Separate .config file

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I took the code from this example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

What I am wondering (and I've been all over the internet today looking) ...
How do you get that to be in an external(separate) file.

The idea I'm going for is:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
      <section
        name="pageAppearance"
        type="HelperAssembly.Configuration.PageAppearanceSection,HelperAssembly"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


  <pageAppearanceGroup fileName="SomeSeparateFile.config"/>

</configuration>
```

..................

The above does not work (of course).

The below is my copying/pasting of the ms article I mention above.
And it was fully functioning when I pasted it here.

```
//START HelperAssembly.csproj

namespace HelperAssembly.Configuration
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Xml;

    public class PageAppearanceSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        // Create a "remoteOnly" attribute.
        [ConfigurationProperty("remoteOnly", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = false)]
        public Boolean RemoteOnly
        {
            get
            {
                return (Boolean)this["remoteOnly"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["remoteOnly"] = value;
            }
        }

        // Create a "font" element.
        [ConfigurationProperty("font")]
        public FontElement Font
        {
            get
            {
                return (FontElement)this["font"];
            }
            set
            { this["font"] = value; }
        }

        // Create a "color element."
        [ConfigurationProperty("color")]
        public ColorElement Color
        {
            get
            {
                return (ColorElement)this["color"];
            }
            set
            { this["color"] = value; }
        }
    }

    // Define the "font" element
    // with "name" and "size" attributes.
    public class FontElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "Arial", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 60)]
        public String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)this["name"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("size", DefaultValue = "12", IsRequired = false)]
        [IntegerValidator(ExcludeRange = false, MaxValue = 24, MinValue = 6)]
        public int Size
        {
            get
            { return (int)this["size"]; }
            set
            { this["size"] = value; }
        }
    }

    // Define the "color" element 
    // with "background" and "foreground" attributes.
    public class ColorElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("background", DefaultValue = "FFFFFF", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", MinLength = 6, MaxLength = 6)]
        public String Background
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)this["background"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["background"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("foreground", DefaultValue = "000000", IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", MinLength = 6, MaxLength = 6)]
        public String Foreground
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)this["foreground"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["foreground"] = value;
            }
        }

    }

}



    namespace HelperAssembly.Configuration
{
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;

    public static class ConfigurationRetriever
    {
        public static PageAppearanceSection RetrievePageAppearanceSection1()
        {
            PageAppearanceSection config = (PageAppearanceSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("pageAppearanceGroup/pageAppearance");
            return config;
        }
}
}



//START ConsoleApplication1.csproj

    using System;

    using HelperAssembly.Configuration;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                PageAppearanceSection pas = ConfigurationRetriever.RetrievePageAppearanceSection1();
                if (null != pas)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pas.Color.Foreground);
                    Console.WriteLine(pas.Color.Background);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception innerException = ex;
                while (null != innerException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(innerException.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\r");

                    Console.WriteLine(innerException.StackTrace);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\r");

                    innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    }



//XML for config file that works with the above code


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <configuration>
       <configSections>
         <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
           <section
        name="pageAppearance"
        type="HelperAssembly.Configuration.PageAppearanceSection,HelperAssembly"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
     </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <pageAppearanceGroup>
    <pageAppearance remoteOnly="true">
      <font name="TimesNewRoman" size="18"/>
      <color background="DEFDEF" foreground="ABCABC"/>
      </pageAppearance>
     </pageAppearanceGroup>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: To include code and/or XML on this site, select it in the editor and press Control-K.

Comment: BTW, did you make any changes to the code you pasted?

Comment: No changes.  The only thing I did was put a space after the < in the xml, and a space before the > in the xml.
But the C# code as copy and paste, and I used the "code" tagger thing in the textblock control.

Comment: You're erroring out because you should extract configSections to separate files, not configSectionGroups.  Moving configSections to separate files is supported by the configuration framework.  Doesn't seem that groups are.  See my changes to your config file below.  I tested them in a sample app and it worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the configSource

http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/dot-net-tips-using-configsource-or-file-attribute-to-externalize-config-sections/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx

Comment: There’s a lit­tle known attribute which was intro­duced in the .Net frame­work 2.0 called con­fig­Source, which allows you to exter­nal­ize sec­tions of the con­fig­u­ra­tion file.

    <appSet­tings file = “rel­a­tive file name” />

but can be added to any con­fig­u­ra­tion sec­tion to spec­ify an exter­nal file for that section:

    <Cus­tom­Sec­tion configSource=“relative file name” />



The above is a quote from the first URL.  (In case it stops existing in the future).

// lit­tle known attribute // End Quote

Now I don't feel so bad.  THANKS!

Answer (score 9):

This will work if you change your app.config to use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
      <section
        name="pageAppearance"
        type="HelperAssembly.Configuration.PageAppearanceSection,HelperAssembly"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <pageAppearanceGroup>
    <pageAppearance configSource="SomeSeparateFile.config"/>
  </pageAppearanceGroup>

</configuration>
```

And your someSeparateFile.config to look like this:

```
<pageAppearance remoteOnly="true">
  <font name="TimesNewRoman" size="18"/>
  <color background="123456" foreground="ABCDEF"/>
</pageAppearance>
```

(no `configuration` element in this file!)

I've been able to move configSections into separate files.  Not sure you can do that with configGroups unless you do a lot more programming.  The configuration framework model lets you move configSections out pretty easily.

Hopefully this helps!!

Comment: //Quote//Not sure you can do that with configGroups unless you do a lot more programming.//End Quote

I was simply staying "true" to the original msdn example on that one.

(I think) the extra configGroups thing is more trouble than it is worth.

Thanks.

...

Comment: @Anvar - no problem...glad I could be of help!

Comment: +1 for noting that you can't use the `configSource` attribute on a `configGroup`.